# GroupBy Statement not grouping like strings

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mask

Evening,

My Data:

```
display(dfRFQ_Breakdown_By_Done_Traded_Away_Grp.sort_values('security_type1',ascending=True))

    state     security_type1    count
0   Done             CORP           239
4   Tied Done        CORP            9
6   Tied Traded Away CORP            7
9   Traded Away      CORP          1075
1   Done             GOVT           40
5   Tied Done        GOVT           2
7   Tied Traded Away GOVT           16
10  Traded Away      GOVT          150
2   Done             MTGE           4
8   Tied Traded Away MTGE           3
11  Traded Away      MTGE           7
3   Done            SUPRA           31
12  Traded Away     SUPRA           88
```

I would like to group all rows with a 'Done' or 'Traded Away' state together for each security_type1:

```
state     security_type1    count
Done        CORP             248
Traded Away CORP             1082
Done        GOVT             42
Traded Away GOVT             166
Done        MTGE             4
Traded Away MTGE             10
Done        SUPRA            31
Traded Away SUPRA            88
```

My code:

```
# Updating any Tied Done to Done and Tied Traded Away to Traded Away  
mask = (dfRFQ_Breakdown_By_Done_Traded_Away_Grp['state'].str.contains('Tied Done'))       
dfRFQ_Breakdown_By_Done_Traded_Away_Grp.loc[mask, 'state'] = 'Done'

mask = (dfRFQ_Breakdown_By_Done_Traded_Away_Grp['state'].str.contains('Tied Traded Away'))       
dfRFQ_Breakdown_By_Done_Traded_Away_Grp.loc[mask, 'state'] = 'Traded Away'
display(dfRFQ_Breakdown_By_Done_Traded_Away_Grp.sort_values('security_type1',ascending=True))
```

It appears the updated strings are being grouped seperately by pandas:

```
state   security_type1  count
Done         CORP        239
Done         CORP        9
Traded Away  CORP        7
Traded Away  CORP        1075
Done         GOVT        40
Done         GOVT        2
Traded Away  GOVT        16
Traded Away  GOVT        150
Done         MTGE        4
Traded Away  MTGE        3
Traded Away  MTGE        7
Done         SUPRA       31
Traded Away  SUPRA       88
```

Whats the resaon for pandas not combining the instances of Done and Traded Away together? Do I need to created another copy of the dataframe. It's almost like pandas has a link to the old values before the updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems possible with [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
res = df.query('(state == "Done") | (state == "TradedAway")')\
        .groupby(['state', 'security_type1'], as_index=False)['count'].sum()\
        .sort_values(['security_type1', 'state'])

print(res)

        state security_type1  count
0        Done           CORP    239
4  TradedAway           CORP   1075
1        Done           GOVT     40
5  TradedAway           GOVT    150
2        Done           MTGE      4
6  TradedAway           MTGE      7
3        Done          SUPRA     31
7  TradedAway          SUPRA     88
```

Comment: Thanks @jpp. Perfect! Avoids the issue all together.